# MySQL alias on name column is not working as intended

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, alias

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT ol.name, o.email AS email, o.phone AS phone, MAX(nrs.created) AS last_subscription, nlf.name AS `neighborhood_name`
FROM organisation AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN organisation_localisation_fallback AS ol ON o.id = ol.organisation_id and ol.language_id=14 and ol.country_id=19
LEFT JOIN neighborhood_request_subscription AS nrs ON o.id = nrs.from_organisation_id
LEFT JOIN organisation_neighborhood AS orgn ON o.id = orgn.organisation_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN neighborhood_localisation_fallback AS nlf ON orgn.neighborhood_id = nlf.neighborhood_id AND nlf.language_id=14 AND nlf.country_id=19
WHERE o.id IN (73)
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY nrs.created IS NOT NULL, nrs.created ASC
```

It is giving me the following columns as a result:

> name | email | phone | last_subscription | name

A result can be seen in this screenshot:
[image: sql error]

I've tried changing the column to be :

- nlf.name as 'neighborhood_name'
- nlf.name as "neighborhood_name"
- nlf.name as `neighborhood_name` (with backticks)
- nlf.name as neighborhood_name
- nlf.name 'neighborhood_name'
- nlf.name neighborhood_name
- ...

None of the above work, they keep giving me back "name" as the column name.
In the query above, i am also unable to change the alias of the first column "ol.name".

Comment: Hello @MaciejLos how do I do this? If i wrap quotes around my column name, it takes that as the value for the entire column ?

Comment: I've tried with single quotes, backticks, double quotes and the backslash. None of them works. When removing the GROUP BY from the query i can change the column. But with the group by it's impossible.

Comment: Apostrophe seems to be working. See: [db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db4c1ffbc081d10fa518f97f15211d92)

Comment: I'm not sure whether [] is valid SQL. I can't get the query to execute by using it as follows: [nlf.name] , [nlf].[name] , nlf.[name] , ...

Comment: Could be an issue with the client (HeidiSQL?). Try runnin the query directly in MySQL.exe.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. The two valid options are `nlf.name as neighborhood_name` and `nlf.name as ``neighborhood_name`` with the `AS` keyword being optional. What I wonder, though: is `nlf.name` functionally dependent on `o.id`? Otherwise you'd need an aggregation function to get this valid, e.g. `ANY_VALUE(nlf.name) AS neighborhood_name`.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions... I tried pasting the query in mysql workbench and the result was the same (can't find the mysql.exe on my windows machine). I couldn't get it working, but I found CONCAT to be a solution that works for me in this case

Comment: So, *is* there just a maximum of one `nlf.name`per `o.id`? Otherwise get your query straight by applying an aggregation function. (`CONCAT` isn't an aggregation function.) Are you working in full group by mode (`SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`)? You should, as this helps to write correct queries.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome the issue by using CONCAT as follows:

```
CONCAT(nlf.name, '') AS neighborhood_name
```